# Arduino millis() elapsed time with pause

Tags: time, arduino

I currently measure elapsed time in my sketch with a code to measure [elapsed time](https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-how-do-you-reset-millis.html) like the one seen here. The code needs to be accurate to about 1 second, but I would like to program it to be as robust as possible.

```
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval) 
{foo;}
```

I'm wondering what the best way to add a pause functionality so that if `bool pause == true` either `previousMillis` or `interval` adjusts to make sure that `foo` fires after `pause==false` for `interval`

Right now I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
//global setup
bool pause=false;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long interval = 1000;
_________
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
RClock();
if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval) 
{
 interval=1000;
 foo;
}

void RClock()
{
  if(pause)
  {
     unsigned long runtime = millis()-previousMillis;
     unsigned long timeleft= interval-runtime;
     previousMillis=millis();
     interval=timeleft;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like it should be a more simple operation.

**Edit**
To clear things up, my goal is for `foo` to trigger when `pause==true` for a total of `interval` so if `interval=1000`(ms) and, during that time, `pause==true` for 500(ms) `foo` would occour after 1500 ms

**Edit 2**

To clarify further, the time something runs before `pause==true` needs to be taken into acount lets say that:

- `interval = 1000`(ms) when the program starts.
- The program runs for 500(ms)
- After 500(ms) `pause == true`
- After 3hr `Pause == false`

  `foo` will be triggered after 500(ms) more of `Pause == false`

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want to "pause the chronometer' while `pause==true`?

Comment: Correct. My end goal is for `foo` to trigger when `pause==true` for a total of `interval`

Comment: where in your code you are assigning `pause=true`? What I understood from question is you want to execute foo for 500ms for every 1000ms, correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pause && ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval))
```

Answer (score 0):

millis() goes back to zero for one millisecond every 50 days.  Hence the extra test.  `PreviousMillis != 0` controls the triggering

```
void Loop()
{
   //...
   if (pause)
   {
      previousMillis = millis();
      if (previousMillis == 0)
        previousMillis = 1;   // avoid the one in a billion chance of missing a trigger
   }
   if (previousMillis && ((millis() - previousMillis) > interval))
   {
      previousMillis = 0;     // prevents retriggering
      foo();
   }
   //...
}
```

The timer is set coninuously withe the current 'time' while `pause == true`.

When not in pause, the timer will pass the second test after `interval` ms.

The timer is set to zero when done; this avoids false triggers.

Comment: does this work as I've mentioned in edit 2? I think it would only count if it ran for when  `pause==false` for `interval` time straight rather than `interval` cumulative.

Comment: @ATE-ENGE I've added a bit of explanation on the logic.

Comment: Writing this out, I don't think it fits what I'm looking for. If `interval = 1000`(ms) and `pause==false` from millis() = 0 to 799, then `pause==true` at millis()=800 to 801, foo would trigger at millis()= 1800 not at 1001

Comment: That's not what you describe in the original question.  "`foo` will be triggered after 500(ms) more of `Pause == false`".

Answer (score 0):

Currently I've written the following code that has the functionality I want, but I'm sure it's not the best way to go about it

(Global Vars)

```
unsigned long time_B  =0
unsigned long time_E = 0
```

(Code)

```
//...
unsigned long RClock (bool reset, bool pause)
{
  unsigned long Ctime=millis();
  if(reset)
  {
    time_B=Ctime;
    //Serial.println("reset");
  }
  if(pause)
  {
    time_B=Ctime-time_E;
    //Serial.println("pause");
  }
  time_E=Ctime-time_B;
  return time_E;  
}
//...
```